# How to plot two series with very different scales in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a beginner in python. I have to plot two graphs in the same plot. One of my graphs is velocity, which ranges between (-1,1), and the other one is groundwater, which ranges between (10,12). When I use the following code, the graphs become very small.

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df=pd.read_excel ('final-all-filters-0.6.xlsx')
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
date = df['Date']
gwl = df['gwl']
v =df['v']
plt.plot(date,gwl, color='deepskyblue',linewidth=2)
plt.plot(date,v, color='black',linewidth=2)
ax1.grid(axis='y')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator())
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator((1,3,5,7,9,11)))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("\n%Y"))
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%b"))
ax1.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.3, linestyle='--')
ax1.grid(which='major', alpha=2)
for spine in ax1.spines.values():
        spine.set_edgecolor('gray')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x',  which='both', colors='gray')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='gray')
ax1.set_ylabel('v', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('GWL', color='b')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But when I add the `ax1.set_ylim(-1, 1)`and `ax2.set_ylim(10, 12)` to my code, one of the graph was disappered!
[image]

Comment: Because you are doing plt.plot(), you are ploting on the same axes. You should do ax1.plot() for the V data, and ax2.plot() for the GWL data. In the current way, I think they go both to the ax2, and that is way the V line disappears. (I am still intrigued why it is not complying with the ylim, though...)

Answer (score 0):

I think it does plot the black graph, but it's out of range. You can check that by adding 11 or something to the black plot value.
Maybe you can try using `ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(-1, 1, 0.5))` instead of `set_ylim` and/or using `ax2.autoscale(enable=True, axis=y)`